# Git: Is there a way to show a subset of lines from a revision?

Tags: git

How can I view a subset of lines from a file in some previous commit.  Normally I do `git show HEAD:path/to/file` but if I'm only interested in a particular area of code I'd like to be able to say, e.g.`git show HEAD:path/to/someFile 33-47` which would show the state of `someFile` at the current HEAD for those lines only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git show HEAD:path/to/someFile | tail -n +33 | head -n $((47-33+1))
```

@ElpieKay provides a cleaner solution with sed:

```
git show HEAD:path/to/someFile | sed -n 33,47p
```

Comment: nice!  i'll have to find a good way to encapsulate this as a bash function like `git-show-lines HEAD 33 47`

Comment: `git show HEAD:path/to/someFile | sed -n 33,47p` makes it a bit simpler.

Answer (score 2):

```
git blame <revision> -L 33,47 <path>
```

Comment: unless theres a convenient flag for 'hide all but line' (which wouldn't make much sense given the command name) i think that @jpkotta's answer is what i'm looking for.

Comment: @AlexBollbach `-s` can remove some of the contents but still not all. It needs extra commands to do the job. `awk` or `sed` are good at it. `-L` can be very useful if you'd like to display the lines of a specific function by `-L :function_name`.